# What is the difference between apache and tomcat in the xampp control panel?

Tags: testing, apache, tomcat, windows-7, install

I installed xampp in my machine. I wonder what is the difference between apache and tomcat in the xampp control panel.

p/s: I started apache only and test with "localhost/index.html", it works.
I started tomcat only, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why xampp included both Tomcat and Apache ?, I think Apache is enough

Answer (score 10):

Apache is the Apache Web Server also known as httpd. See http://httpd.apache.org

Tomcat is Apache Tomcat. See http://tomcat.apache.org

httpd is a web server whereas Tomcat is a Servlet Container. While at the simplest level both can be viewed as web servers that serve static files they have very different focuses. httpd is typically used to host static content and dynamic content written in perl, php amongst others. Tomcat is primarily intended to be used to serve web applications developed in Java to the Java Servlet specification.

Comment: Wait, wait, `httpd` is the official name of that project?

Comment: No. The official name is "Apache HTTP Server". See the minutes from back in 1999 when the PMC was established: http://www.apache.org/foundation/records/minutes/1999/board_minutes_1999_04_13.txt